# Dealloc called while method is still running

Tags: objective-c, ios, synchronized

In a project I'm working on (I picked up this code and I've been trying to debug it), I have a function that gets called by an observer.  The observer calls a method that updates data to be put on a screen.  While this update is happening (it takes a few seconds for the updates to occur), a user can press the 'Back' button on the navigation bar, which causes a dealloc call to occur.  While the method is running, the dealloc call releases all of the ivars, which eventually causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS when the method attempts to access the ivars.  The structure of the update method is also enclosed with a `@synchronized` block.

```
- (void)update {

@synchronized(self){
  // some code here...
  // Also access ivars here.
  }

}
```

What can be done to tell the controller to finish the method first before deallocating?  I've tried running a while loop with a condition in the dealloc, but that doesn't seem efficient.  It also never fully executes if the controller is released, and stays in a deadlock.  I feel like the solution is simple, but my brain is fried from a long day at work and I can't think about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `retain` on `self` to ensure the reference count does not reach zero while running a longer running method; and avoid the dealloc that way:

```
- (void) update {
    [self retain]

    // do work ...

    [self release]
 }
```

Comment: Note that you can't do this under Automatic Reference Counting.

Comment: This solved the issue for me! I didn't realize how silly simple this was. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you put the work you need to do in a block, the compiler will automatically retain all the objects referenced inside the block (including self).  For example:

```
- (void)update {
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        // some code here, access ivars, do whatever you want
    }];
}
```

The update method will immediately return and the block will be scheduled to run on the main run loop (no secondary threads are involved here).

If the update work is a long-running task, you can use a background queue instead of the main one, and then (inside that block) schedule another block to run on the main queue and interact with the UI when the work is done.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are talking about the NavigationBar my guess is that what is happening is that your NavigationController is releasing its reference to your UIViewController class, which in turn is holding the ivars. One way around it is to retain the objects inside the viewcontroller until the calcuations are made, as the other answers suggest. However if the calculations you are doing are made to calculate what data should be shown in that view, the next time you open the same view, you will reload the view again from the beginning.

What I would do is that I would keep a reference to the ViewController that you are working with outside of the navigationcontroller, so that it does not get released when the user presses the back button.

Then later, if the user comes back to the same view, you will already have the data loaded. Just push it again using the same reference.

Example:

```
@interface YourRootViewController : UIViewController {
    YourNextControllerClass *nextController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) YourNextControllerClass *nextController;

@end
```

In the ViewDidLoad of your top ViewController:

```
self.nextController = [[[YourNextControllerClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourNextControllerNib" bundle:nil] autorelease];
```

When you want to show the view:

```
[myNavigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];
```

If the user presses the back button, the viewcontroller will not be released, so when you push it again, everything will be there as you left it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on whether you want to keep that object alive to the end of the method or not. However, you also use @synchronized (self): I would be very afraid what happens if self gets deallocated and the @synchronized tries to remove the lock on self, so in this case I would try to keep it alive. (However, @synchronised and then running lots of code is not a good idea in my opinion; @synchronised should be used for the smallest amount of code possible to avoid deadlocks).

With ARC, keeping the object alive within the method is simple.

```
typeof (self) myself = self;
```

will create a strong reference to self. And better to use myself in the method body instead of self.

If you don't want to keep the object "self" alive, which would be the usual case:

```
__weak typeof (self) weakSelf = self;
```

Then wherever you want to make sure that self is still there you write

```
typeof (self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
if (strongSelf != nil) {
}
```